# Having an issue with checkbox v-model only returning the first keyword in array

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, v-model

I have several tracks in an array and have a search and checkboxes to filter the tracks. However, the checkboxes only return the first identified string in each filter. So if I click the checkbox for pop - in the example below - it will only show tracks containing only the pop genre. Tracks containing rock, pop genre won't appear. This is in composition API in Vue.

Here is the script:

```
const searchTerm = ref('')

const genreFilter = ref([])
const moodsFilter = ref([])
const tempoFilter = ref([])
const themeFilter = ref([])

const filteredTracks = computed(() => {
let filtered = useSong.tracks;

if (searchTerm.value) {
const term = searchTerm.value.toLowerCase();
filtered = filtered.filter(track =>
  track.description.toLowerCase().includes(term) || 
  track.genre.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||
  track.keywords.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||
  track.moods.toLowerCase().includes(term)
);
}

if (genreFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => genreFilter.value.includes(track.genre))
}

if (moodsFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => moodsFilter.value.includes(track.moods))
}

if (tempoFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => tempoFilter.value.includes(track.tempo))
}

if (themeFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => themeFilter.value.includes(track.theme))
}

return filtered;
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="genres w-1/4"><h1 class="font-bold text-[#aeaeae]">Genres</h1><br>
        <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Rock" key="genre" value="Rock" v- 
 model="genreFilter">
        <label class="css-label pl-2 text-s font-light text-[#aeaeae]" for="Rock">Rock</label> 

        <input class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Pop" key="genre" value="Pop" v- 
 model="genreFilter">
        <label class="css-label pl-2 text-s font-light text-[#aeaeae]" for="Pop">Pop</label>
```

How can I modify this so that I can check multiple boxes of genres and have them all show, removing only the unchecked boxes. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Also, you'll notice in the filters I have one for moods, tempo and theme. Whenever I click any of those checkboxes, nothing appears at all in the array despite the array having matching moods, tempo, and theme.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `genreFilter` variable is an array:

```
const genreFilter = ref([])
```

But you put the whole thing into the checkboxes' `v-model`:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Rock" v-model="genreFilter">
```

effectively replacing the array with a string.

So when you do

```
filtered = filtered.filter(track => genreFilter.value.includes(track.genre))
```

You are not calling `Array.prototype.includes()`, but `String.prototype.includes()`. Which works, but not as you intended.

Simple solution is to use indexes in the checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Rock" v-model="genreFilter[0]">
```

A probably better solution is to add or remove elements when checking the checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Rock" @change="updateGeneres($event.target)">
```

and

```
const updateGenres = ({value, checked}) => checked 
? (genreFilter.value.includes(value) || genreFilter.value.push(value))
: (genreFilter.value = genreFilter.value.filter(g => g !== value))
```

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed} = Vue;

const App = {
  setup(){
    const genres = ['Rock', 'Pop']
    const genreFilter = ref([])
    const updateGenres = ({value, checked}) => checked
      ? (genreFilter.value.includes(value) || genreFilter.value.push(value))
      : (genreFilter.value = genreFilter.value.filter(g => g !== value))
    const items = [
      {genre: 'Pop', title: 'This is Pop'},
      {genre: 'Rock', title: 'This is Rock'},
      {genre: 'Something Else', title: 'This is something else'},
    ]
    const filteredItems = computed(() => genreFilter.value.length === 0 ? items : items.filter(i => genreFilter.value.includes(i.genre) ))
    return {genres, genreFilter, updateGenres, filteredItems}
  },
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  
  <div v-for="genre in genres">
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox" 
        :value="genre" 
        @change="updateGenres($event.target)"
      > {{ genre }}
    </label>
  </div>
  
  Selected Genres: {{genreFilter}}
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems">{{ item.title }}</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Here is the snippet in a [SFC with setup script](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I couldn't get this working properly the way you said above with what I already have. Here is the full template https://codeshare.io/zyz8jE I'm new to JS so it's pretty confusing to me. I got it working in a single page app with a JS file for the array and all the script but now I've been breaking it into components I can't work out the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is what I had previously before breaking it into components. https://codeshare.io/YLZoqm

Comment: Did you see the snippet? It should contain all you need. You shouldn't have to do mare than to copy the `updateGenere()` function into your setup script and then replace all `v-model="genreFilter"` on the checkboxes with `@change="updateGeneres($event.target)"`. Does that work?

Comment: No sorry. I still can't get it working. When I add the code from the snippet I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: $setup.updateGenres is not a function
    at _createElementVNode.onChange._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (MusicView.vue:163:111)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345:9)

Comment: Hmm, I had a typo in the answer `upateGenre` instead of `updateGenre`, you probably copied that too (sorry!). Just make sure that the function in the script has the same name as in the event handlers.

Comment: Hi @MoritzRingler I changed the typo before trying it and then got the error above unfortunately.

Comment: It think the error means that there is no`updateGenres` function declared in your setup script. Impossible to say from afar, but should be easy to fix with some debugging. If you can provide a sandbox, I can have a look, but if you don't know how to do it, you are probably better off learning it. Check that the variable is declared in the setup script, check that it is callable, check the component using the Vue debugger, make sure there is no other error in the log and so on.

Comment: I have added to the answer a link to a sandbox which contains above snippet in a SFC, so you can see that it works.

Comment: Haven't heard back from you - did you get it to work?

Comment: Hi @MoritzRingler unfortunately not. I tried the exact way you said but it I can't get it to update the SongRow component of the app, I tried it both as a Filter component and importing it to the MusicView.vue page and putting it directly in the page. I think I'll have to look at indexing next.

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that. Seems like there are some fundamentals you need to figure out before you can get to the issue of this question. Anyway, if you feel my answer addresses the question of how to filter a list through checkboxes, please consider leaving a vote or marking it as accepted answer.